# Getting page title in Firefox add-on using Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to get page title on every page using new Firefox add-on builder. How can I do that?

**Edit** 
More info
I want to get page title on every page load event .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually the very first example for the [`tabs` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html):

```js
var tabs = require("tabs");
for each (var tab in tabs)
  console.log(tab.title);
```

See [tab.title](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html#title).

**Edit**: If you need to know the title of each page as it loads rather than capture the current state then you should use the [`page-mod` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html):

```js
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: "end",
  contentScript: 'console.log(document.title);'
});
```

The documentation has some info on how a content script can communicate with the add-on, e.g. to send it this page title.

If you are only interested in top-level documents then you can still use the `tabs` package:

```js
var tabs = require("tabs");
tabs.on("ready", function(tab) {
  console.log(tab.title);
});
```

Comment: will it get called on each page load ?

Comment: @VivekGoel: Of course not. I've updated the answer to your changed question. When asking on Stack Overflow it is generally a good idea to mention what you tried and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: sorry my mistake will take care about that in future

Answer (score 0):

"ready" events won't get fired if the page is served from back-forward cache.
'pageshow' event is the appropriate event to listen to.

```html
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

function onOpen(tab) {
tab.on('pageshow', function(tab) {
           console.log('title: '+ tab.title);
  }

tabs.on('open', onOpen);
```